# How to allow only once rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

i have a class called `PeopleData`.

i want to mock call on `PeopleData` to raise error. so i did this

```rb
allow(PeopleData).to receive(:fire_api).with(anything).and_raise(StandardError, "Error Here")
```

There are two classes call this `PeopleData`. First is `TrafficData`, and second is `ClimateData`.

`TrafficData` call `PeopleData` to get some data. I want to test rescue block in `TrafficData` when there is error on `PeopleData` call. So i did this

```rb
allow(PeopleData).to receive(:fire_api).with(anything).and_raise(StandardError, "Error Here")
expect(TrafficData.call).not_to raise_error
```

and it is fine. because it was expected. the rescue block is called and return something.

`ClimateData` class call using parameter data from `TrafficData` and it also call `PeopleData`. i want to test `ClimateData` call and return something without rescue anything.

But the problem is because i allow `PeopleData` to raise error, it will raise error also on `ClimateData`

This is what i did

```rb
allow(PeopleData).to receive(:fire_api).with(anything).and_raise(StandardError, "Error Here")
expect(TrafficData.call).not_to raise_error
expect do
   ClimateData.check_climate!
end.to return(data)
```

it show error like this

```rb
raise StandardError, check_status.to_s
```

on the line in `check_climate` method definition.

Question: How to allow `PeopleData` mocking call ONLY ONCE? only in `expect(TrafficData.call).not_to raise_error`

so when i call `ClimateData.check_climate!`  it will not raise error

Comment: Are the two calls to `fire_api` identical?

Comment: I think you can do `allow(PeopleData).to receive(:fire_api).with(anything).once.and_raise(StandardError, "Error Here")`

Comment: this is not the way test case should be wrote, it looks like you write test case follow or base on the code you already wrote, you want to find the way `somehow the test cases will pass` with your current code. NO, the test MUST BE: ok,here the case: `PeopleData` will certainly raise error (since you define `with(anything)`, right?) then `TrafficData` does not raise error and `ClimateData` will return result, that it, don't touch me, refactor your code instead.

Comment: So either you should rescue error also on `ClimateData` (refactor code) or replace with another test case like: allow `PeopleData` will raise error with `params1, params2` and will not raise error with `params3, params4` (which be return by `TrafficData`), so that `ClimateData` will not raise error, as you can see, 2 test cases, 2 scenario, and make sense. Write Test First.

Comment: @Stefan yes they call same `fire_api` with different parameters

Comment: @LamPhan can we do that? i mean first i `allow(PeopleData).to receive(:fire_api).with(anything)` and the other is `allow(PeopleData).to receive(:fire_api).with(param1, param2)` and not throw error?

Comment: @dedypuji then replace `with(anything)` with something more specific.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```rb
values = [proc { raise 'Error Here' }]
allow(PeopleData).to receive(:fire_api).and_wrap_original do |original, *args|
  values.empty? ? original.call(*args) : values.shift.call
end
```

Comment: Using `.and_wrap_original` is indeed the way to simulate "intermittent" failures. Unfortunately using `@values` ivar is often necessary. Also, beware that `[nil].empty? #=> true` (when attempting to mock intermittently missing value).